# "Incomplete \ifcase" error depends not on the \ifcase but the integer at which it's evaluated

Tags: programming

I have a puzzling `Incomplete \ifcase; all text was ignored after…` error in that the same `\ifcase` is fine if I evaluate it at the largest integer for which it's defined, but if I evaluate it at a smaller integer, I get the error.

I show three versions. All are identical except (a) whether I comment out two lines of code for case "3" and (b) the integer at which the `\ifcase` is evaluated.

My question: Why does Version 2 give me the `Incomplete \ifcase` error?

Version 1: Defined up to case "2" and evaluated at "2". No problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
%   When the \ifcase is defined up to case 2, and evaluated at 2, all is well.
\newcommand{\expandedmulticolumn}[1]{
\ifcase#1
%Zero case. Nothing to see here.
\or %case 1
\multicolumn{2}{c}{A}%
\or %case 2
\multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B}%
%\or %case 3
%\multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C}%
\else
You've blown my mind.\\
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|cc|cc|cc|} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\expandedmulticolumn{2} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Version 2: Defined up to case "3" but still evaluated at "2" => Get the `Incomplete \ifcase` error.

```
\documentclass{article}
%   When the \ifcase is defined up to case 3, and evaluated at 2, error: 
\newcommand{\expandedmulticolumn}[1]{
\ifcase#1
%Zero case. Nothing to see here.
\or %case 1
\multicolumn{2}{c}{A}%
\or %case 2
\multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B}%
\or %case 3
\multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C}%
\else
You've blown my mind.\\
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|cc|cc|cc|} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\expandedmulticolumn{2} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Version 3: Defined up to case "3" and evaluated at "3". No problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
%   When the \ifcase is defined up to case 3, and evaluated at 3, all is well again. 
\newcommand{\expandedmulticolumn}[1]{
\ifcase#1
%Zero case. Nothing to see here.
\or %case 1
\multicolumn{2}{c}{A}%
\or %case 2
\multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B}%
\or %case 3
\multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C}%
\else
You've blown my mind.\\
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|cc|cc|cc|} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\expandedmulticolumn{3} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the simpler situation

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\ifcase 1 \or x&y\or x&y\fi
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Since the integer is 1, TeX skips over the case zero and leaves in the input stream

```
x&y\or x&y\fi
```

Conditionals in tabular material are always complicated, because explicit `&` are scanned in order to keep track of cells and this code has the `\fi` too “far away” (in a different cell), whereas TeX wants to complete the `\ifcase` before the current cell ends.

Here's a different solution, in which TeX will only “see” the tokens corresponding to the chosen case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\expandedmulticolumn}{m}
 {
  \int_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {1}{\multicolumn{2}{c}{A}}
    {2}{\multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B}}
    {3}{\multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C}}
   }
   {You've~blown~my~mind.}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|cc|cc|cc|}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\expandedmulticolumn{3} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub>You're still hiding what you want to actually do. Leaving aside `forloop` is a good step. I'm certain that `expl3` will help you much more, but without more information…</sub>

Comment: this is a perfect solution for what I need. I haven't been trying to "hide the ball" ("You're still hiding what you want to actually do…"), but to create a MWE I wound up abstracting away from what I wanted to do. This solution, however, is exactly what I need to do.

Answer (score 9):

if the value is 1 then the `&` which are being skipped over *still* end the table cell and the current group and the rest of the `or` and matching `\fi` are not seen until a later table cell. You need to hide the table markup in a macro or group so that it is only seen in the case that it is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
%   When the \ifcase is defined up to case 3, and evaluated at 2, error: 
\def\zz{&}
\newcommand{\expandedmulticolumn}[1]{
\ifcase#1
%Zero case. Nothing to see here.
\or %case 1
\multicolumn{2}{c}{A}%
\or %case 2
\multicolumn{2}{c}{A} \zz \multicolumn{2}{c}{B}%
\or %case 3
\multicolumn{2}{c}{A} \zz \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} \zz \multicolumn{2}{c}{C}%
\else
You've blown my mind.\\
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|cc|cc|cc|} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\expandedmulticolumn{2} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```